# Delete only those records from Master when 'sku' and 'link' match with the child table

Tags: sql

I want to delete only those records from Master when sku and link match with the child table

```
DECLARE @MASTER TABLE
(
SKU VARCHAR (50),
LINK VARCHAR (100)
)

INSERT @MASTER

SELECT 'A7061B',    'IMG_A7061S_A7061B.jpg' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A7063B',    'IMG_A7063S_A7063B.jpg' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A7065B',    'IMG_A7065S_A7065B.jpg'

SELECT * FROM @MASTER


DECLARE @CHILD TABLE

(
SKU VARCHAR (50),
LINK VARCHAR (100)
)

INSERT @CHILD

SELECT 'A7061B',    'IMG_A7061S_A7061B.jpg' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A7063B',    'IMG_A7063S_A7063B.jpg' 

SELECT * FROM @CHILD
```

Expected Output

only below records should be deleted.

```
SKU,    LINK
A7061B, IMG_A7061S_A7061B.jpg
A7063B, IMG_A7063S_A7063B.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you need a query like the following:

```
DELETE m
FROM @MASTER AS m
INNER JOIN @CHILD AS c ON m.LINK = c.LINK AND m.SKU = c.SKU
```